# How to restrict CKEditor to paste only 2000 characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have integrated CKEditor in my JSF file. I need to allow only 2000 characters in the editor but while pasting it is taking more than 2000 characters. How can I restrict the editor to take only 2000 characters.

Comment: You can't. At least not reliably. Browsers do NOT have access to a user's clipboard without their permission. So you can't count the characters in there before it's already pasted in your editor. You could attach an event handler to count the characters inside the editor after the paste and just remove everything after the 2000 count. But JS is still client side. It's easily possible to remove your limitation and go wild. Reliable checking will have to be done server side no matter what.

Comment: how can we implement the check on server side?

Comment: The same way you would validate any property in JSF

Answer (score 0):

If you not already are, you can use PrimeFaces Extensions library, which contains the [`pe:ckEditor`](http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/ckEditor.jsf) component. You can simply add a `f:validateLength` validator to it like:

```html
<pe:ckEditor ...>
  <f:validateLength maximum="2000"/>
</pe:ckEditor>
```